# Изменение ссылок при деплое на Heroku

Tags: java, сервер, heroku

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с проблемой при деплое своего сайта на Heroku. Все сделал правильно и сайт отображается, но все ссылки которые были в проекте не работают, потому что все было настроено локально.

Вот собственно и сам вопрос, как всю организовать так, что при деплое WAR файла на Herooku все отображалось корректно?

Comment: использовать пути не абсолютные пути http://localhost/sity/url, а относильные /sity/url

Comment: Окей, а из JavaScript как тогда обращать к rest ссылкам?